# Programatically Finding Powershell Parameter Default Values

Tags: .net, vb.net, powershell, reflection

I have a script, with a parameter and a default value, such as:

```
<#
  Help Info snipped...
#> 
param(
  [string]$MyParameter = "Whatever" ,
)
```

When I query that parameter, by running in an interactive session

```
(get-help C:\whatever\wherever\myscript.ps1 -Parameter MyParameter).defaultValue
```

I get "Whatever", just as I expect.

However, when I Invoke that same snippet of code from my application, using the code:

```
    Dim inputString As String = "(get-help C:\whatever\wherever\myscript.ps1  -Parameter MyParameter).defaultValue"


    Using powerShellObject As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
        Dim powershellCommand As PSCommand = powerShellObject.Commands.AddScript(inputString)


        For Each r As PSObject In powerShellObject.Invoke
            Debug.Print(r.BaseObject)
        next
..blah blah blah
```

I get back nothing (i.e. the variable r is nothing).

Now, if I change the script snippit that I run to something like

```
(get-help get-process -parameter ComputerName)
```

I will get (from an interactive session) "Local Computer", and from the code above, I'll get "Local Computer" in r.BaseObject.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try executing just `"(get-help C:\whatever\wherever\myscript.ps1)"` to see if you are getting any help info back.  Also, check the powerShellObject.Streams.Error collection to see if you are getting any non-terminating errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break into the Visual Studio debugger, and hover over the result variable, you'll find that you have to drill down further to get any useful information. Furthermore, you'll also have to do some type casting in order to access the appropriate members to get the information you're after.

For example, here I am aggregating the array of "description" strings together, to grab the "Description" of the `-ComputerName` parameter for the `Invoke-Command` command.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddCommand("Get-Help");
    ps.AddParameter("Name", "Invoke-Command");
    ps.AddParameter("Parameter", "ComputerName");
    var result = ps.Invoke();
    var result2 = ((PSObject[])result[0].Members["description"].Value).Select(psobj => psobj.Members["Text"].Value).Aggregate((text, mystr) => text + ", " + mystr);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
    //Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(' ', result[0].Members["description"].Value));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image: Results]
[image: Visual Studio Debugger]